# why "»" shows as a question mark("?") in my page?

Tags: special-characters

Is there any restrictions for it to show normally?

Comment: A link to the actual page will net you much more specific advice.

Comment: By the way, I would recommend you to check out this page for further problems : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like an encoding problem. For special characters like that, I prefer to use HTML entities. In this case, try &raquo;

Answer (score 3):

After my experience, a question mark usually replaces undecodable special characters when you encode your special characters with utf8, because web browsers by default decode the web page using iso-latin1. You can/should explicitely declare the encoding of your web page using the following directive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

for xhtml, or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
```

(inside the  element), for HTML.

Regard this post as a supplement, because I guess that using the xml/html entities like `&raquo;` or `&#187;` mentioned above are the better way to go.

Comment: Or, as the meta tag suggests, you can also use the correct HTTP `Content-type` header: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: @Lèse, sorry, did not mean to put this old thread on the front page again. I just coincidentally found a flaw in my answer and corrected that. Didn't think that might even bring in another 10 rep points :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use &#187;

Answer (score 0):

If your Apache server is configured with...

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

...in the httpd.conf file (which, strangely, was the default on my server), then Content-Type specs in the .html files (e.g., <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">) will be ignored, causing character codes above 127 to be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment out the AddDefaultCharset line and restart Apache.